# JavaScript: не работает value

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Пишу один сайт, пригодились формы, но столкнулся с тем, что value не отображает. Может кто знает, как чинить?

Код с jquery:

```
function inputval() {
  var inp = $("#inputId").val();
  return inp; 
}
```

Ещё на чистом js, так же - не отображает:

```
function inputval() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
  return inp; 
}
```

В общем, не возвращает.

Comment: "value не отображает" - что не отображает, где не отображает? *"Мое недоумение разделяла все Европа." В.Ерофеев "Москва - Петушки"*

Comment: @Igor например, `alert(inputval())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. Вы вызываете `inputval()` до того, как в инпут вводится значение.

Вариант 2. У Вас на странице больше одного элемента с `id="inputId"`.

Comment: нет, вызываю после.

Comment: @likel0vsky Нет, вызываете до.

Answer (score 0):

Покажи сам инпут:

```js
function inputval() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
    return inp; 
  }    
  
btn.onclick = () => {
  let btn = inputval()
  console.log(btn)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId">
<button id = 'btn'>Test</button>
```